# Detect line-change only changes in git

Tags: git

Question 1:
Is there a way I can get git to list all the files that have been modified that differ only in line endings?

Question 2:
how can I pass a list of files to git to checkout cleanly (aka roll back uncommitted changes on list of files)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1, you can get that list by comparing these two outputs from a revision:

```
git show --pretty= --name-only some-revision
git show --pretty= -w --name-only some-revision
```

The files that are in list 1 and that are gone from list 2 are the ones that only changed the EOL... so, if could be scripted like this:

```
git show --pretty= --name-only some-revision | while read file; do
    lines=$( git show --pretty= -w --name-only some-revision -- "$file" | wc -l )
    if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

If you are talking about what is going on in the working directory at the time:

```
git diff --name-only | while read file; do
    lines=$( git diff -w --name-only -- "$file" | wc -l )
    if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: when I set revision to HEAD this show only appears to show me the last commit. I am looking to find the unstaged changes that differ only in line ending.